# Unprotect workbook while opening with password

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open protected workbook which is encrypt with password and password is "password".

I write below code but its not working.

please help on this.

```
Sub demo()
Dim path_file As Variant
path_file = "c:\login\FloorLoginData.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open(path_file).Unprotect Password:="password"
end sub
```

Comment: *"its not working"* is no useful error description. Instead describe what happens or which errors you get.

Comment: Thanks Peh, its again ask to enter password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look into the documentation of the [Workbooks.Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) you will see that it has a `Password` parameter.

```
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim PathFile As String
    PathFile = "c:\login\FloorLoginData.xlsx"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=PathFile, Password:="password")
End Sub
```

*Note: Don't use* `Variant` *if you can use* `String`*.* `Variant` *is the worst choice as variable type, always use something else if you can.*